# How to set tab order for all elements from a list view?

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, tabs

We have a UWP application. In one xaml view, we are using a `ListView` control. 
The `ListView` shows a list for 2 textboxes. We need to set the tab order to be from left to right and top to bottom. 
By setting `IsTabStop` to false in the list view, the tab works only for first row from the list.

Does anyone know how to set tab order for list view elements?

Answer (score 2):

> We need to set tab order to be from left to right and top to bottom.

There is [`TabNavigation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.tabnavigation) property in ListView, if we want to make the listview could be tabbed from left to right and top to bottom, we could set the value of TabNavigation as `Local` like the follow. Then, the tab key will focus on the element in whole ListView.

```
<ListView  IsTabStop="False" TabNavigation="Local"/>
```